# Unable to SSH to my EC2 instance despite adding my IP in the security group route table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, timeout

I have tried all that I could have done.

1. Deleted the previous EC2 instances
2. Used a new key pair
3. Used putty to connect with new pair
4. Used chrome extension secure shell app to connect to EC2 instance with new key pair
5. I added my IP address in my security group inbound table but not able to access the EC2 instances.

Attached are the images of my issues.

[image: Error image]
[image: Error image] 
[image: Error image]

Comment: Why is your SSH client trying to connect to port 80 rather than 22?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of the problem:**

The port number for SSH is 22. 
However, the screenshot for the ssh error shows that the connection is being attempted on port 80.

**Suggested fix:**

The problem can be fixed by specifying the port number as '**22**' in the SSH client connection settings.

Comment: I did it, but the issue persists, good catch by the way. 

I anticipate the issue being with the routing table, I have added my IP address in the Table but somehow the new addition to the routing table does not APPLY. 

How do I make the "APPLY" the changes that I have done in the routing table?

Comment: If the Linux EC2 instance is created in a public subnet, then the default security group and default routing table are sufficient to allow SSH access. No change is required for either the security group or routing table.  If ssh is not working with the default security group and default routing table, then the problem is definitely not with AWS. The problem in this scenario could be with a firewall in the client side network blocking outbound SSH connection to AWS.

Comment: I have added my IP address in my routing table but somehow so that I can allow me to connect, but somehow I cant find how to apply the routing table configuration.

Comment: You should be modifying a Security Group, _not_ a Route Table.

Answer (score 0):

To access the EC2 instance via SSH, check:

- The instance has been launched in a public subnet (defined as having a Route Table that routes traffic to an Internet Gateway)
- The Security Group should be permitting inbound traffic on port 22 from your IP address (or a wider range, such as `0.0.0.0/0`)
- Don't change the NACLs from default
- Make sure the instance is running Linux
- For *EC2 Instance Connect*, make sure it is using **Amazon Linux 2** or Ubuntu 16.04 or later
- Make sure you are connecting to the public IP address of the instance (based on your pictures, you are doing this)

Simple hint: If the connection takes a long time to fail (or hangs), then there is **no network connectivity to the instance**. Check Security Groups and VPC configurations. If an error comes back immediately, then network connectivity is okay and the connection is simply being refused by the instance.

Comment: you are right, the EC2 instance is taking a long time to fail.